# Obtaining Russian citizenship

Tags: russia

As far as I can tell one can obtain Russian citizenship but I can't find a procedure on how.  One way is through marriage but are there any others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the political-related comments have been removed, I'll refrain from suggesting your friend to move to Crimea.

Other than that - [here are the rules](http://www.ufms.spb.ru/desc/prijom-v-dind-65.html). I won't quote since they actually [change quite frequently](http://www.ufms.spb.ru/desc/) (the latest change was a couple of weeks ago). You can always find the up-to-date information at UFMS websites. Warning - it's in Russian. Apparently, being fluent in Russian is a prerequisite for naturalization.

Comment: Wasn't quite the destination I suggested...